# Initialising an integer pointer with a value at its pointee's address there itself

Tags: c, string, pointers, string-literals

For instance, consider;

```
char* a = "coding is fun";
```

I have understood that this line will create a pointer and put the string literal at its pointee's address.

Is that dereference operator actually doing its job there or is it just a part of the syntax and is just to tell the compiler to create a pointer data type?

Because if it really is working as a dereferencing operator there than => `int* a = 5;` should also put the value of 5 at the pointee's address of pointer a.

If not, then how is the former code snippet valid?

Comment: it is "_just to tell the compiler to create a pointer data type_"

Comment: `i have understood that this line will create a pointer and put the string literal at its pointee's address.` No, it creates an array and declare `a` as a pointer to the first element of that array

Comment: You can make an array of integer `int a[] = {5}`, it can be decayed to a pointer when you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of a statement like

```
 char* a = "coding is fun";
```

the dereference operator `*` is **not** used for any dereference. The `*` here can be considered as part of the *type* itself to denote that the variable is a pointer type, i.e., the type of the variable `a` is `char *`, i.e., pointer to a `char`.

That statement is basically creating an unnamed array, filling that with the `coding is fun` with the null-terminator and then, by assigning that *unnamed array* to the pointer, making the pointer point to the first element of that array, becasuse as per `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.1

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the
>   unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
>   type *‘‘array of type’’* is converted to an expression with type *‘‘pointer to type’’* that points
>   to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. [...]

To add to that,

```
 int* a = 5;
```

is a **valid syntax** but **invalid usage**, because, there, you try to *store* the `int` value `5` as a pointer-to-`int` type, which is highly platform defined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It's valid because the language specification says it is.

You can expect 100% symmetry and orthogonality from C's syntax, but you're going to be disappointed. :)

Basically, you can read

```
char *a = "coding is fun";
```

as a shortcut for:

```
char a_string[] = "coding is fun";
char *a = a_string;
```

where, of course, the first line is a shortcut for:

```
char a_string[] = { 'c', 'o', 'd', 'i', 'n', 'g', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'f', 'u', 'n', '\0' };
```

Obviously the name `a_string` is never introduced for real, but this is how it could be working under the hood.

No such shortcut exists for integers, but that's fine since no equivalent to the double-quoting exists either (your `int *b = 5;` example has a plain-looking `5`, while the string example has a bunch of characters in double quotes).

Answer (score 0):

The string literal becomes a pointer to an array living in the read only part of the process memory. (There is no such thing in the C standard, but that's how things actually work.)

So what you actually have is

```
char * a = <the said address>.
```

There is no such equivalent for integer values, so no, what you think doesn't work.

Comment: Well, by C standard writing into the string literal is UB, so it is assumed read-only.

Comment: BTW. [*Like string literals, const-qualified compound literals can be placed into read-only memory and can even be shared.*](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5p13)

Answer (score 0):

`int* a = 5` sets the variable `a` to point to address `5`.

`char* a = "coding is fun"` sets the variable `a` to point to the address of the `"coding is fun"` string, determined according to where the compiler/linker places it within the executable image.

Typically, it will reside in a read-only segment, but this is not dictated by the C-language standard.

Answer (score 0):

> For instance, consider;
>
> ```
> char* a = "coding is fun";
> ```
>
> I have understood that this line will create a pointer and put the
>   string literal at its pointee's address.

You've got that backward.  The line declares a variable, `a`, of type `char *` (pointer to `char`), and initializes it with a pointer value that points to the first character of the given string literal.  The literal itself represents an array of `char`.  Its location is chosen by the compiler, and has nothing to do with the location of `a`, and certainly nothing to do with the indeterminate value that `a` would start with if it were not initialized.

> Is that dereference operator actually doing its job there or is it
>   just a part of the syntax and is just to tell the compiler to create a
>   pointer data type?

It is not a dereferencing operator at all; it is part of the specification of the type of `a`.

> Because if it really is working as a dereferencing operator there than
>   => int* a = 5; should also put the value of 5 at the pointee's address of pointer a.

Your alternative definition of `a` as an `int *` is invalid because the expression `5` has type `int`, and assignment to a variable of pointer type requires the value assigned to have compatible pointer type, to have type `void *`, or to be a null pointer constant.  Many compilers will still accept it, however, usually with a warning, because C allows `int`s to be converted to pointers (technically requiring a cast).  In any event, the result is not a pointer that can be dereferenced to get the value `5`, but a pointer that maybe can be *converted* to `5`.  This is the difference between evaluating `*a` and evaluating `(int)a`.

> If not, then how is the former code snippet valid?

A string literal has type array of *n* `char`, where *n* is the number of `chars` in the literal, plus one for a terminator.  In almost all C contexts, when a (sub-)expression of array type is evaluated, the result is a pointer to the first array element.  In the case of evaluating a string literal, the type of the resulting pointer is `char *`, which is also the declared type of `a`.  What could be wrong with assigning a value of a given type to a non-`const` variable with exactly the same type?